# Having trouble matching parameters to this signature of call target JS/TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
public getAll({ refresh }: { refresh?: boolean } = {}): Observable<Model[]> {
        return this._getAll({ refresh: refresh });
}
```

how could I call this function so that the refresh in `this._getAll` is set to true? And in general what does this syntax mean?

Comment: nice ghost downvote. Are there just trolls who fly around downvoting questions. This is a totally reasonable question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it like `getAll({ refresh: true })`. You can read more about this syntax [here](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html). This is just syntax sugar from ES6 standard.